# how to initialize and print a 2-d array of characters?

Tags: c

```
char name[5][5]={  ""         };

printf("%s",&name[0][0]);
```

I just want to know why "&" is used in printf.
and why [][0] the second parenthesis has a '0' in it?

similarly

```
char *name[5][5]={    ""       };

printf("%s",&name[0][0]);
```

why here also & is used?

I'm simply not able to understand .
in array of pointers shouldn't there be * instead of &?

Comment: book..and they  are working correctly on turboc/c++

Comment: @hacks My bad , had tripped a bit .

Comment: Why are you still using Turbo C? It's already dead. I'm guessing this is a requirement in a university.

Comment: @Sean Ballais I use either gcc or visual c++ on my main machine

Comment: I see. You might wanna take a look at Clang too. It's an excellent compiler.

Comment: @SeanBallais I guess I have used that..if I'm not wrong it is in CS50 appliance.

Comment: Yes, `clang` is in the CS50 appliance.

Answer (score 1):

`%s` expects an argument of type `char *`. `&name[0][0]` is of type `char *`.  `&name[0][0]` is the address of the first character of first string. If you want to print the first string from the beginning, you have to use `&name[0][0]`.
Using `&name[0][1]` will print the string from its second character, `&name[0][2]` from third character and so on provided the string is long enough.

Comment: thanks now I got that.
if I just use &name[0] ..that will also work?

Comment: @lord_ozb; No. Just use `name[0]`. Its type is array type but will convert to `char *` type.